# Difference in Bluetooth scanning and discovery on Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

There are two approaches defined in the Android to find out bluetooth devices. 
1. Using bluetoothAdapter.startScan
2. bluetoothAdapter.discover

which approach is better.

2nd question,
In onLeScan callback, how to check if scanning has been stopped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These methods apply to different versions of Bluetooth. Which one to use depends on what kind of device you have.

Classic Bluetooth uses `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` to find devices which are discoverable.

Bluetooth Low Energy support was added in API level 18, it uses `BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(ScanCallback)`. As of API level 21 this is replaced by `BluetoothLeScanner.startScan()`.

See [this samplecode](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/DeviceScanActivity.html) on how to scan for LE devices. In `onLeScan` if you've found the device just call `scanLeDevice(false);`.

The onLeScan callback does not check if scanning has been stopped. You have to give the `stopLeScan()` command yourself.

Comment: Hi JPS, thanks for your reply. my second query was, How to check in onLeScan callback if method has been called from onStartScan or onStopScan. I have one more query, i have only one bluetooth device but after starting scanning, multiple time onLeScan is getting called and giving same device result. it would be helpful if you can suggest some code snippet for the onLeScan method, for startScan and stopScan both.

Comment: That's right. You can check in the onLeScan callback if you've found the right device and then you can stop scanning, just call adapter.stopLeScan(). I'll add a link to sample code in my reply.

Answer (score 1):

`startScan()` will be scanning for LE devices, `startDiscovery()` for normal bluetooth devices.

As far I know `startLeScan()` or `startScan()` will scan as long as method `stopLeScan()` or `stopScan()` will be called and you must call them.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the startDiscovery() method of BluetoothAdapter and i use Broadcast receiver to know if i have scan result, scan is stopped etc..

The BroadcastReceiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver scanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
                        // device found

                    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(
                            BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)) {
                        // discoveryFinished

                    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(
                            BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED)) {
                        // discoveryStarted

                    } 

                }

            };
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);

            activity.registerReceiver(scanReceiver, filter);
```

You should register this Broadcast Receiver before you start discovering